Integral calculation of$ \int_{1}^{e}\frac{\ln^{2}\left(x\right)}{x\left(1+\ln\left(x\right)\right)}dx$
I've been trying to calculate the area of this integral:
$$
\int_{1}^{\rm e}\frac{\ln^{2}\left(x\right)}{x\left[1 + \ln\left(x\right)\right]}{\rm d}x
$$
and the answer that I get is
$\ln\left(2\right) - 1/2 = 0.19\ldots$.

However, in the final results of my academy, it shows that this answer:
$$
\frac{{\rm e}^{2}}{2} - {\rm e} +
\ln\left(\frac{{\rm e} + 1}{2}\right) + \frac{1}{2}
$$
is the correct one which is $2.096\ldots$
I even tried to use chatGPT, which also reaches the answer: $\ln\left(2\right) - 1/2$.
It'd be helpful if someone could help me figure it out![enter image description here][1]

[enter image description here][1]
I also used to calculate the integral with subtitution with $y$ of $ln(x)$ $(y = ln(x) )$ + differential: $dy = dx/x => dy/x=dx$ . And I also used the polynomial long division.

You need to enclose all your MathJax expressions in dollar signs.

There is no linked image

I've added dollar signs

Hi, welcome to Math SE. Whatever ChaptGPT told you, it's actually $\ln2-\frac12$. It's not very good at maths, I'm afraid. Hint: substitute $u=\ln x$ to rewrite the integral as $\int_0^1(u-1+\frac{1}{u+1})\mathrm{d}u$.

@fGDu94: but not to the title!

Sorry, I meant to say: $ln(2) - 1/2$, I forgot to add this. And the chat also reached that answer so it actually had the correct answer too :)

$$I=\int_{1}^{e}\frac{\ln^{2}\left(x\right)}{x\left(1+\ln\left(x\right)\right)}dx$$
$ln(x)=t$, $\frac{dx}{x}=dt$
$$I=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{t^2}{1+t}dt=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{t^2-1+1}{1+t}dt=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{(t-1)(t+1)+1}{1+t}dt$$
$$I=\int_{0}^{1}t-1+\frac{1}{1+t},dt=\frac{t^2}{2}-t+ln(1+t)|_0^1=\frac{1}{2}-1+ln(2)-\left(0\right)=ln(2)-\frac{1}{2}$$
I strongly suggest to stay away from chatgpt for math

At 50 points level expected for asking questions is higher .

The result of your academy result is for
$$\int_{\color{red}{e}}^{\color{red}{e^e}}\frac{\ln^{2}\left(x\right)}{x\left(1+\ln\left(x\right)\right)}\,dx=\frac{{\rm e}^{2}}{2} - {\rm e} +\ln\left(\frac{{\rm e} + 1}{2}\right) + \frac{1}{2}.$$

The results of your academy are incorrect, Wolfram alpha gives $\ln(2)-\frac{1}{2}$. To find this, consider the substitution $u = \ln(x)$. Then two rounds of integration by parts.
