Integral area of $\int_{1}^{e}\frac{3\ln\left(x\right)}{x \sqrt{\ln^{2}\left(x+1\right)}}dx$
Could someone please help me to solve this integral area:
$\int_{1}^{e}\frac{3\ln\left(x\right)}{x\cdot\sqrt{\ln^{2}\left(x+1\right)}}dx$
I have no clue how to do it and I tried to do substitution and integration by parts, but nothing works...
Steps:
First Subsitution:
$u=ln(x+1)$ and
$dx=(x+1)du$
From the substitution of $u=ln(x+1)$:
$x=e^u−1$
and $e^u = x+1$
Then, substitute that into the integral:
$\int_{1}^{e}\frac{3\ln\left(e^u−1\right)}{e^u−1-u}(e^u)du$
Then, I do integral by parts for ${3e^u\ln\left(e^u−1\right)}$ and another substitution, but it doesn't work and I don't have a clue how I finally summarise the results to the original integral:
$3u*ln\left(e^u−1\right) - \int_{1}^{e}\frac{3u\left(e^u\right)}{e^u−1}du$
Second Substitution:
$t=e^u−1$, $e^u=t+1 => u=ln(t+1)$ and $du=dt/(t+1)$
From here I don't know what to do...

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Why not simplifying the square root with the square? The logarithm is positive in the interval of integration

I did it, but when I try to subtitute I'm still stuck and unable to continue

@YuvalYanay Can you elaborate on what you tried ?

@sam I added now the elaboration to the body

This is as much as I can say: The integral equates to $3 \int_{0}^{1} {\big[ 1 + \ln \left( 1 + {e}^{- x} \right) / x \big]}^{- 1} \text {d} x$.

Most probably, there's simply a typo, with $\ln^2(x+1)$ meant to be $\ln^2 x+1$, which makes the problem easy to solve. (The square root of the square of a positive number looks suspicious.)

@metamorphy. I think that you found thé problem

Looks like another question with typo similar to what op posted before https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4934487/integral-calculation-of-int-1e-frac-ln2-leftx-rightx-left1-ln-l
